# TChart in C++Builder 6.0 rotate chart

Tags: c++builder, axis, teechart

Can I rotate a chart? I need x on vertical axis and y on horizontal axis.
Can I change x value to vertical axis and y value to horizontal axis?
Or can I rotate of the component TChart (xy values stay standard and I flip component 90)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would probably be to use swap your values or add your X values as YValues and add your y values as XValues.
Ie, let's say you have your X values in an array called Xdata and your Y values in an array called Ydata. You could add your values with this:

```
Series1->AddXY(Ydata, Xdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can write - i used a line(fast line) chart.

There
[IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/29atrw5.png[/IMG]
is Classical graph and image if I rotate it. If I change x-y values as You wrote I get wrong image.

- y = f(x) so it paint for x=1, x=2, ... but i need paint x = f(y) for y=1, y=2, y=3

I need something as is point chart - connect handly in paint

I'm not sure if it is possible change axis or rotate component teeChart.
I probably use TImage and will paint it into image.

Answer (score 0):

today i find that teechart have a series "horiz line" (https://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/java/v1/docs/Tutorials/tutorial1.htm).
But licence is expensive for our company (https://www.steema.com/buy). We need only one chart with this axes.

Do you know if can I install only some update into BCB 6?